# KahaDB and LevelDB - What's the real difference?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, difference, leveldb

I'm trying to use `ActiveMQ 5.8.0` in my project. There are two different storage configurations, `KahaDB` and `LevelDB`. Depending on the problem, Kaha can be faster than Level or Level can be faster than Kaha.

What's the real difference between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The two stores are similar in that they both utilize an index to track the location and state of messages written into a Journal.  The differences lay in the way in which the index is implemented among other things.  LevelDB is a slightly faster index than KahaDB and can provide somewhat better performance numbers.  In later releases of ActiveMQ the LevelDB store also supports replication.

Given that you are on an older release where the LevelDB store implementation was still very young I'd recommend sticking with KahaDB as it is much more mature and has many of the early bugs worked out.  The LevelDB store in 5.8 is not really production ready and will probably cause you some trouble.  You can move to the newest release v5.10 and LevelDB will be much more robust.

NOTE: LevelDB has been deprecated by the community and is not supported any longer.  It will likely be fully removed in ActiveMQ 5.17.0

Comment: Using both I decided to use Kaha because it's more secure than Level cause it stores messages on disk everytime. LevelDB run messages into memory and then save it to disk, so in production if the system's down i lose my messages. Is this right?

Comment: No, both use a disk based journal to store all operations, the differences are in how the index is maintained but the index can be recreated from the journal so there is no message loss for persistent messages

Comment: See it, but I can't understand why LevelDB is so slow to write/read into my machine. It's the same code and the last ActiveMQ (v5.10) but it still slowly than KahaDB... Is there some recomended configuration? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

I would stay away from LevelDB for ActiveMQ for any new projects. The KahaDB, LevelDB picture changed somewhat.

> The LevelDB store has been deprecated and is no longer supported or recommended for use. The recommended store is KahaDB

You will see this in the LevelDB documentation:
http://activemq.apache.org/leveldb-store.html

So the KahaDB, LevelDB picture changed somewhat. We considered using LevelDB for a production setup with 3 ActiveMQ instances monitored by 3 Zookeeper instances.  The prototype worked quite nice, except when simulating an ActiveMQ instance crash, we experienced occasional LevelDB corruptions during the restart of that instance.

You now have the following choices when persistent messaging is required:

- Use Apache ActiveMQ and a database as persistent message store (jdbc)
- Use a shared block level or file level share file system (NFS, CIFS or even GlusterFS) for the KahaDB message store and work with ActiveMQ Master / Slave
- Apache ActiveMQ Artemis
- Apache Kafka

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend.

Comment: As said in my comment, the doc is not clear if LevelDB has been deprecated or not as another page says it will be the new default storage. As you also mention, switching to Artemis could be a better option for production ready solution.

Comment: And in our case we also have ActiveMQ crashes but with the KahaDB storage. then it looks like the option would be another setup. We're thinking if we don't share the KahaDB between AMQ instance it would perhaps be better (Network of Broker, instead Master Slave).

Comment: [leveldb documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/leveldb-store.html) seems to indicate that it should no longer being considered for production use.  We are also looking at a setup that is a network of master-slave brokers using multiple kahadb instances for storage. The idea is that if a master fails, the slave will takeover for any node containing a master and slave. We therefore shouldn't suffer from stalled message inside an instance that is stopped. there should always be a slave that promotes to master and allows consumption or does a forward of the message in the network of brokers